# What is a clearer way to generate this sequence of numbers?

Tags: python, math

I have to generate a list like this:

```
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]
```

and this is my current code

```
g = lambda x: x + g(x - 2) if x > 0 else 0
print([g(2 * i) for i in range(10)])
```

Is there a clearer and more direct way to generate the sequence?

Comment: Waht is the algorithm behind this (in words)?

Comment: You mean, it looks way too readable?

Comment: What is fixed, what is variable?

Comment: If I've correctly understood your algorithm `[sum(range(0, i+1, 2)) for i in range(0, 20, 2)]` is both shorter and more readable.

Comment: Why "No"? If you just want to generate `[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]`, just print it. It doesn't get any easier.

Comment: @bereal Kindly look at wim's code. It is much more readable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These appear to be the first few [pronic numbers](http://oeis.org/A002378).  That is, a number which is the product of two consecutive integers, `n * (n + 1)`.

[image: sequence]

I've found this by searching in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).  It's simple to generate them with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x*(x + 1) for x in range(10)]
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]
```

Comment: @wim: If you want to provide the number as a function of n, then g = lambda x: x * (x + 1) will to the trick. You can then use g(n) in a list comprehension or somewhere else.

Comment: If you actually read more of what you linked to, you might have noticed that the word "pronic" is incorrect and it should be "promic".

Comment: @martineau really?  would you like to edit the mathworld and wikipedia articles aswell?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number ,  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PromicNumber.html   correct or not historically, it seems to be the commonly accepted word these days

Comment: Yes, as also stated in the mathworld article: "pronic" seems to be a misspelling of "promic" -- although admittedly it does go on to say correcting it now is "seems inadvisable" (as in futile).

Comment: It is not too hard to prove that this is the correct closed form for the recursion.

Comment: Yes, for example `sum([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20])` can be re-ordered like `sum([0, 20, 2, 18, 4, 16, 6, 14, 8, 12, 10])` i.e. `sum([20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10])` etc ... actually its the same trick that euler used to quickly sum the numbers 1..100 :)

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is, as @wim has already pointed out, for "pronic numbers", and can be summarised to:

> The `n`-th pronic number is the sum of the first `n` even integers

You can therefore write it as:

```
def pronic(n):
    """Create a list of the first n pronic numbers."""
    return [sum(range(0, 2*i+1, 2)) for i in range(n)]
```

However, while this is a clear implementation of the approach you've taken, the other definition can make it even neater, as @wim's answer shows.

You could also consider implementation as a generator:

```
def pronic():
    """Generate the pronic numbers."""
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i * (i + 1)
        i += 1
```

Comment: The first snippet looks `O(n^2)`-ish.

Comment: @bereal I make no claim to efficiency, and wim's answer is clearly better; I provide this only as a clearer implementation of the OP's current algorithm.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to limit the generator, a non-terminating while loop would be more appropriate there

Comment: @wim good point, edited

Comment: You voted to close the question as _"unclear what you're asking"_ after you had answered it. I can understand doing one or the other, but both?...

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [x+(x ** 2) for x in range(10)]
print list1

Output : [0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]
```

This will give you the series that you have asked for.

Comment: Nice observation @Sesha.

Comment: Indeed, and therefore `[x*x+x for x in range(10)]` would work, too, and it involves only multiplication and addition for each term.

Comment: This is just an expanded version of the same algorithm `x*(x + 1) = x*x + x = x + (x ** 2)`, nothing particularly new or useful here